# fast double exp2 function in C

Tags: c, approximation, exp, math-functions

I need a version of the following fast exp2 function working in double precision, can you help me ? Please don't answer saying that it is an approximation so a double version is pointless and casting the result to (double) is enough..thanks. The function which I found somewhere and which works for me is the following and it is much faster than exp2f(), but unfortunately I could not find any double precision version:

```
inline float fastexp2(float p)
{
 if(p<-126.f) p= -126.f;
 int w=(int)p;
 float z=p-(float)w;
 if(p<0.f) z+= 1.f;
 union {uint32_t i; float f;} v={(uint32_t)((1<<23)*(p+121.2740575f+27.7280233f/(4.84252568f -z)-1.49012907f * z)) };
 return v.f;
}
```

Comment: Look here: https://bduvenhage.me/performance/machine_learning/2019/06/04/fast-exp.html

Comment: This formula doesn't compile: `error: expected '}' before ')' token`

Comment: Re “Please don't answer saying that it is an approximation so a double version is pointless and casting the result to (double) is enough..thanks”: Why? What do you want that converting the result of the code in the question to `double` would not provide? Do you want a more accurate approximation? How much more? Do you just want it rewritten in `double`, so it does `double` arithmetic with the same values? Do you want a wider range? You need to specify the criteria of the problem.

Comment: elena, please post a version that compiles.

Comment: elena, The `int w = (int) p;` step fails when `p` is much greater than `INT_MAX`.  If you are looking for only a function that work for a sub-range of `float`, what is that range?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo..it should compile fine now

Comment: The function is from a fastmaths.h by Paul Mineiro found somewhere.

Comment: @Eric I am working with doubles but a cast seems stupid to me because my assumption is that if this approximation working with 32 bits floats can offer a given precision, the same approximation trick working with 64 bits double shall necessarily offer a better precision.

Comment: My range is limited say from -10 to 10 the int overflow is not an issue in my case

Comment: @elena: Constants in approximations like this are commonly tailored to the precision of the floating-point format being used. Changing the format to `double` gets you more precision in the calculations but it does not improve the designed constants. As my note on nuffa’s answer says, the `double` precision is often less accurate than the `float` version and, when it is better, it is often not by much.

Comment: double fast_expd(double x) {
  x*=(1.0/ 64.0);
  x = 1.0 + x*(1.0 + x*(0.5+x*0.166666666666666666));
  x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x; x *= x;
  return x;
}

Answer (score 5):

My assumption is that the existing code from the question assumes IEEE-754 binary floating-point computation, in particular mapping C's `float` type to IEEE-754's `binary32` format.

The existing code suggests that only floating-point results in the normal range are of interest: subnormal results are avoided by clamping the input from below and overflow is ignored. So for `float` computation valid inputs are in the interval [-126, 128). By exhaustive test, I found that the maximum relative error of the function in the question is 7.16e-5, and that the root-mean-square (RMS) error is 1.36e-5.

My assumption is that the desired change to `double` computation should widen the range of allowed inputs to [-1022, 1024), and that identical relative accuracy should be maintained. The code is written in a fairly cryptic fashion. So as a first step, I rearranged it into a more readable version. In a second step, I tweaked the coefficients of the core approximation so as to minimize the maximum relative error. This results in the following ISO-C99 code:

```c
/* compute 2**p, for p in [-126, 128). Maximum relative error: 5.04e-5; RMS error: 1.03e-5 */
float fastexp2 (float p)
{
    const int FP32_MIN_EXPO = -126; // exponent of minimum binary32 normal
    const int FP32_MANT_BITS = 23;  // number of stored mantissa (significand) bits
    const int FP32_EXPO_BIAS = 127; // binary32 exponent bias
    float res;

    p = (p < FP32_MIN_EXPO) ? FP32_MIN_EXPO : p; // clamp below
    /* 2**p = 2**(w+z), with w an integer and z in [0, 1) */
    float w = floorf (p); // integral part
    float z = p - w;      // fractional part
    /* approximate 2**z-1 for z in [0, 1) */
    float approx = -0x1.6e7592p+2f + 0x1.bba764p+4f / (0x1.35ed00p+2f - z) - 0x1.f5e546p-2f * z;
    /* assemble the exponent and mantissa components into final result */
    int32_t resi = ((1 << FP32_MANT_BITS) * (w + FP32_EXPO_BIAS + approx));
    memcpy (&res, &resi, sizeof res);
    return res;
}
```

Refactoring and retuning of the coefficients resulted in slight improvements in accuracy, with maximum relative error of 5.04e-5 and RMS error of 1.03e-5. It should be noted that floating-point arithmetic is generally not associative, therefore any re-association of floating-point operations, either by manual code changes or compiler transformations could affect the stated accuracy and requires careful re-testing.

I do not expect any need to modify the code as it compiles into efficient machine code for common architectures, as can be seen from trial compilations with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org), e.g. [gcc with x86-64](https://godbolt.org/z/6GYxjf) or [gcc with ARM64](https://godbolt.org/z/sqW35v).

At this point it is obvious what needs to be changed for switching to `double` computation. Change all instances of `float` to `double`, all instances of `int32_t` to `int64_t`, change type suffixes for literal constants and math functions, and change the floating-point format specific parameters for IEEE-754 `binary32` to those for IEEE-754 `binary64`. The core approximation needs re-tuning to make best possible use of double precision coefficients in the core approximation.

```c
/* compute 2**p, for p in [-1022, 1024). Maximum relative error: 4.93e-5. RMS error: 9.91e-6 */
double fastexp2 (double p)
{
    const int FP64_MIN_EXPO = -1022; // exponent of minimum binary64 normal
    const int FP64_MANT_BITS = 52;   // number of stored mantissa (significand) bits
    const int FP64_EXPO_BIAS = 1023; // binary64 exponent bias
    double res;

    p = (p < FP64_MIN_EXPO) ? FP64_MIN_EXPO : p; // clamp below
    /* 2**p = 2**(w+z), with w an integer and z in [0, 1) */
    double w = floor (p); // integral part
    double z = p - w;     // fractional part
    /* approximate 2**z-1 for z in [0, 1) */
    double approx = -0x1.6e75d58p+2 + 0x1.bba7414p+4 / (0x1.35eccbap+2 - z) - 0x1.f5e53c2p-2 * z;
    /* assemble the exponent and mantissa components into final result */
    int64_t resi = ((1LL << FP64_MANT_BITS) * (w + FP64_EXPO_BIAS + approx));
    memcpy (&res, &resi, sizeof res);
    return res;
}
```

Both maximum relative error and root-mean-square error decreases very slightly to 4.93e-5 and 9.91e-6, respectively. This is as expected, because for an approximation that is roughly accurate to 15 bits it matters little whether intermediate computation is performed with 24 bits of precision or 53 bits of precision. The computation uses a division, and this tends to be slower for `double` than for `float` on all platforms I am familiar with, so the double-precision port doesn't seem to provide any significant advantages other than perhaps eliminating conversion overhead if the calling code uses double-precision computation.

Comment: Njuffa thanks a LOT for your time, that was exactly what I needed ! I could not spend time to reverse engineer the float version and make a double version by myself presently. It works well. Thanks!

Comment: A quick test near all multiples of  .1 in [−10, +10] shows the `float` version of the function is more accurate 76 times out of 201!

Comment: @njuffa: I am not faulting your work, just a little surprised by the behavior. Even if the coefficients were tailored for `float`, I would guess that the `float` results would have additional errors due to rounding in the calculations with `float` precision. Even if the last term dominates, the average error would be around ¼ of a `float` ULP, whereas the `double` calculations would have a relatively negligible error contribution. However, my mind set was for a good approximation that aimed for near-ULP accuracy, so ¼ ULP would be a lot for it…

Comment: … But looking at the results, the errors seem to be commonly in the dozens of ULPs. So the `float` calculation errors do not add much. But, still, why are they so frequently better than `double`? If the `double` calculation error is tiny, then the `float` calculation error must be “correcting” the polynomial approximation. That does not seem likely. What is lurking in there?

Comment: Actually after testing well the double version by njuffa in some cases it is more accurate by one digit and in some cases else it is less by one digit. After optimization (read: making it unreadable lol) it is still 5% slower than the float counterpart. It's a pity, without going into the details behind the function I really hoped to get a better approximation using double. I mean, for that 5% lost in speed I pretty get nothing on the average over the float function...

Comment: @eric: but can't those constants be increased in precision ? I can't understand where they come from but despite the fp hex format used (which I never heard of despite being a long date c coder lol) they still look single precision constants, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @elena: Yes, the constants before today’s edit are single-precision (in the sense they are values that are representable in single precision; none has more than 24 bits in the significant, which is easily seen since they have one bit before the “.” (they are all “1.”) and six digits (24 bits) after, but they all end with an even digit, so only 23 are used, which makes 1+23=24, the width of the IEEE-754 binary32 significand. Hexadecimal floating-point constants have been in the C standard since 1999.

Comment: @elena: Using more precision does not create more accuracy. Consider that one has some polynomial p(x) that approximates 2^x. It approximates 2^x with some accuracy (whether measured as minimum maximum error or some other metric). If that accuracy is around 2^-20, in the ballpark of this one, then calculating it with `float` adds a little in the way of rounding errors (maybe averaging 2^-25 for each operation, but compounding in various ways). So the accuracy will still be around 2^-20. Calculating it in `double` changes the rounding errors to around 2^-54 each, but the polynomial error…

Comment: … is still around 2^-20. The accuracy (or lack thereof) in the polynomial approximation is the limiting factor, not the precision used to calculate. So you need to not just convert the routine from `float` to `double` but redesign the polynomial that approximates the function. That is a complicated job that not many people in the world do, and few do well. But you came to us and ask for a “fast double” version of the function. And njuffa delivered that. If you are disappointed, it is to be expected, because you did not tell us what your accuracy goals truly were, just asking for…

Comment: … a new routine to be delivered in a particular way. Not stating the problem requirements properly is part of the reason this question was voted down and closed.